# Как организовать длительное подключение к серверу? p3.6 сокеты

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я, например, пытаюсь подключиться к серверу:

```
sock.connect(('localhost', 1111))
```

Но если в этот момент порт не открыт, то вылечу с ошибкой `ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение` . Как сделать так, чтобы он пытался подключиться дальше, а не вылетал с исключением?
И ещё вопрос. Если я подключился и шлю сообщения:

```
 sock.send("\0".encode("utf-8"))
```

А потом вдруг порт закрылся. При попытке отправить будет снова исключение и стоп программы. Я могу отловить его и снова пытаться подключиться?

```
try:
    sock.send("\0".encode("utf-8"))
except ConnectionResetError:
    #снова пробую подключиться
```

Если да, то мне вероятно понадобится здесь способ из первой части этого топика. Спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: Просто заверните этот код в цикл?

Comment: Сделайте бесконечный цикл, в нем connect. Если соединиться не удалось, то делаем time.sleep() на некоторое время, т.е. ждем немного и уходим на второй круг (continue). то же происходит и при исключениях при отправке, уходим опять на начало цикла

Comment: @Mike "Если соединиться не удалось" это я как должен определить? Отловить исключение?

Comment: да, отловить исключение